# VBA code creates a ghost image on active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

When I run a macro on my spreadsheet I get an overlay of one of the other sheets in the spreadsheet which covers a section of the screen and the only way to get rid of it is to scroll or select another sheet

A link to another forum I tried
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1067951-running-a-certain-macro-results-in-a-ghost-image-of-another-sheet.html#post3995238

**Code**

```
Sub Hardware()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Integer

x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0).Activate

Cells(x + 1, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Table ID?")
Cells(x + 1, 3).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Date It Was Purchased?")
Cells(x + 1, 4).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Item Purchased?")
Cells(x + 1, 5).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Which File Tab?")
Cells(x + 1, 6).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Any Notes?")
Cells(x + 1, 7).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Quantity of item?")
Cells(x + 1, 8).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Total Cost?")

ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: In order to help, the problem you have should be reproducible (i.e. please provide a code snippet that reproduces the problem). But I guess it depends on external factor (such as screen resolution, operating system etc.)

Comment: the spreadsheet I am using is a company one which holds private data such as purchasing etc

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a "ghost" image, but the actual image of another sheet that you use during the execution of your VBA macros.

Add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to your code, this should fix it. (set it to true once you are finished updating/calculating stuff)

Comment: I have already added in that piece of code however it does not seem to cure the problem, it stops it from happening during the macro running however it still occurs after it's finished

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or something? After the macro has finished running your worksheets will get visibly updated. Apart from that nothing else should happen

Comment: I guess the lower part is the problem? Are you sure that your VBA does not in fact copy stuff from your first sheet to the one in the screenshot? Also did you reenable the screen updating by using `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of your function?

Comment: Yes it is and yeah it has recently only just started to happen I use a macro to navigate to the sheet then the code I supplied allows me to input data into the table. There is no code I know of that will copy any information across from my first sheet.